# QGIS create link line features between table points by point names

Tags: qgis

I have two CSV data sets: `points CSV` and `links CSV`.
I have easily generated nodes in QGIS but I do not know how to make lines between the points.
There must be an applicable tutorial or previous post - please help, here are the details:

1. point data CSV example, first ten points

> ```
> "Manhole_ID","Manhole_No","Coord1","Coord2","Cover_Level","Inflow","No_Of_Pipes","Pipe1","Pipe2","Pipe3","Pipe4","Population"
> "C15D","MHA1",98922.34,2872997.45,1394.85,100.00,1,1,0,0,0,0
> "C15C","MHA2",98915.48,2872937.84,1392.28,100.00,2,1,2,0,0,0
> "C158","MHA3",98910.56,2872895.19,1390.41,100.00,2,2,3,0,0,0
> "C151","MHA4",98905.44,2872850.74,1388.69,0.00,3,3,4,21,0,0
> "C150","MHA5",98894.93,2872759.60,1384.62,20.00,2,4,5,0,0,0
> "C14F","MHA6",98883.49,2872660.26,1379.75,0.00,2,5,6,0,0,0
> "C14C","MHA7",98872.04,2872560.92,1373.89,0.00,2,6,7,0,0,0
> "C148","MHA8",98865.84,2872507.10,1370.33,20.00,2,7,8,0,0,0
> "C145","MHA9",98865.28,2872502.26,1370.04,0.00,2,8,9,0,0,0
> "C142","MHA10",98851.69,2872491.85,1369.28,0.00,3,9,10,24,0,0
> ```

2. line data CSV example

> ```
> "PIPE_ID","Pipe_No","Upstream_MH","Up_MH_Invert","Downstream_MH","Down_MH_Invert"
> AEFB,1,MHA1,1393.55,MHA2,1390.99
> AEFF,2,MHA2,1390.99,MHA3,1389.12
> ADE4,3,MHA3,1389.12,MHA4,1387.4
> ADE5,4,MHA4,1387.4,MHA5,1383.12
> ADE6,5,MHA5,1383.12,MHA6,1378.25
> ADE7,6,MHA6,1378.25,MHA7,1372.39
> ADE8,7,MHA7,1372.39,MHA8,1368.83
> ADE9,8,MHA8,1368.83,MHA9,1368.54
> C128,9,MHA9,1368.54,MHA10,1367.27
> ```

The lines need to use the node names `upstream_mh = manhole_no` and `downstream_mh = manhole_no` to draw line features

Comment: forgot to mention ... the SID used here is 2053 Hartebeesthoek wgs84 29   http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2053/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool in QGIS called **"Points to Paths"**, you can find it under
`Processing-->Toolbox-->QGIS geoalgorithms --> Vector creation`.

You will need to preprocess your data though. This tool needs a Group field, based on which it knows which points belong to one line.

So this is what you need to do:
In the **points.csv** duplicate your points, with the exception of the first and last point. Add a field called "**Pipe_No**" and fill this field with the pipe nr.
Eg:

```
Manhole_ID,Manhole_No,Coord1,Coord2,Cover_Level,Inflow,No_Of_Pipes,Pipe1,Pipe2,Pipe3,Pipe4,Population,Pipe_No
C15D,MHA1,98922.34,2872997.45,1394.85,100,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
C15C,MHA2,98915.48,2872937.84,1392.28,100,2,1,2,0,0,0,1
C15C,MHA2,98915.48,2872937.84,1392.28,100,2,1,2,0,0,0,2
C158,MHA3,98910.56,2872895.19,1390.41,100,2,2,3,0,0,0,2
C158,MHA3,98910.56,2872895.19,1390.41,100,2,2,3,0,0,0,3
C151,MHA4,98905.44,2872850.74,1388.69,0,3,3,4,21,0,0,3
C151,MHA4,98905.44,2872850.74,1388.69,0,3,3,4,21,0,0,4
C150,MHA5,98894.93,2872759.6,1384.62,20,2,4,5,0,0,0,4
C150,MHA5,98894.93,2872759.6,1384.62,20,2,4,5,0,0,0,5
C14F,MHA6,98883.49,2872660.26,1379.75,0,2,5,6,0,0,0,5
C14F,MHA6,98883.49,2872660.26,1379.75,0,2,5,6,0,0,0,6
C14C,MHA7,98872.04,2872560.92,1373.89,0,2,6,7,0,0,0,6
C14C,MHA7,98872.04,2872560.92,1373.89,0,2,6,7,0,0,0,7
C148,MHA8,98865.84,2872507.1,1370.33,20,2,7,8,0,0,0,7
C148,MHA8,98865.84,2872507.1,1370.33,20,2,7,8,0,0,0,8
C145,MHA9,98865.28,2872502.26,1370.04,0,2,8,9,0,0,0,8
C145,MHA9,98865.28,2872502.26,1370.04,0,2,8,9,0,0,0,9
C142,MHA10,98851.69,2872491.85,1369.28,0,3,9,10,24,0,0,9
```

If your dataset is too big, work with excel or with a database.

Load this into QGIS, start the Points to Path tool and fill the fields like this out:
[image: Points to Path]

This creates a line layer of the point pairs.
Now you need to **join** this layer with your **lines.csv**
To do this:
 1. Import the lines.csv but **only the attribute table**
 2. Rightclick on your `lines layer --> properties --> joins --> +`
 3. Choose the "group" field from your lines layer, and "Pipe_No" from the lines.csv to join the data.
For the joining part here is a [good tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/performing_table_joins.html).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe more simple if I got it right.
If MHA1 has to be connected to MHA2 that has to be connected to MHA3 and so on in **this order**, then just add a column grp with a 1 in all fields for example (or whatever you want) it is just to use an aggregation in :

```
select makeline(p.geometry) as geom, p.grp from thepoints p
group by p.grp
```

[image]

was it you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

Late, but for future help, if you have starting and ending points coordinates (joining the points table to the links table would do the job):
Using xy to lines tool creates lines between the points.
[image: xy to Line]

[image: Tool parameters]